# Почему появляется ошибка json.decoder.JSONDecodeError и как ее победить?

Tags: python

Ошибка следующая:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0

Сам код

```
import requests

url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?alt=json"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
for video in data['feed']['entry'][0:6]:
    print(video['title']['$t'])
```

Comment: Потому что эта ссылка возвращает не json, а [строчку `No longer available`](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?alt=json)?

Comment: [В общем](https://github.com/madscheme/introducing-python/issues/3), можно заменить ссылку на https://raw.githubusercontent.com/koki0702/introducing-python/master/dummy_api/youTube_top_rated.json

Comment: Версия python какая?
На 2.7 у меня работает.

Comment: третья, 3.6 кажется